# Batch file and other scripts on windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, scripting, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

is thee a way to make a all the scripts in a specific folder running without the need of the UAC prompt?

or maybe using power-shell to run the scripts without using "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"

is there any way to just mark some scripts of the folder that contain them as trusted to run on the server?

Comment: I've never left UAC enabled on a server, but I'm willing to accept that it may not be best practice.

Comment: well most of the servers are not administrated by us, it's for our customers, and I do not believe they would like to disable the UAC, some of them are very critical security must be maintained well !!!!!

Comment: most people say not to disable uac but MS has come up with a new KB on this subject http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2526083

Answer (score 1):

I would disable UAC.  It offers no actual protection and is 100% useless.  You could also try right-clicking the file and setting the "Run as administrator" option.  Also, depending on where the file came from, where you copied it, and what OS you are using, you may need to "unlock" the file.

Here's how to unlock a file:

- Right click the file
- Property
- Tab "General"
- Click on "unlock file"

Answer (score 0):

you can mark shares and folders trusted like a website (configuration is in internet explorer),
but that doesnt avoid UAC. UAC is not folder specific so the short answer to your question is "no".

also there is no "batch way" of elevating rights. BUT there are a few workarounds.
one would be to make a shortcut on the bat and mark "run as admin" in the compatibility settings.
more workarounds are possible, this question comes up every few days on stackoverflow, so you probably find an answer there

Comment: Thanks, I searched the internet for a solution, and I did not find something teat really helps us, but maybe if we signed our PS scripts that might help right?

Comment: sorry never worked with signed PS scripts

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Elevator](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinzugec/archive/2008/05/19/elevator-command-line.aspx), although I think this compromises the effectiveness of UAC.